# validation error not displayed for all fields using javascript in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using JavaScript in JSP page and trying to display errors in all fields if no value is provided in the input field.. but for some reason error message is displayed only for the the first field which is field label.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <h1 class="text-success text-center">Test Test</h1>
        <div class="col-lg-8 m-auto d block">

            <form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" class="bg-light">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>FieldLabel:</label> <input type="text" name="fieldLabel"
                    class="form-control" id="fieldLabel"></input> <span
                    id="fieldLabelError" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Version:</label> <input type="text" name="version"
                    class="form-control" id="version"></input> <span id="versionError"
                    class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"
                onclick="validation()">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validation() {
        var fieldLabel = document.getElementById("fieldLabel").value;
        var version = document.getElementById("version").value;
            if (fieldLabel == "") {
            document.getElementById("fieldLabelError").innerHTML = "**Please enter Field label";
            return false;
        }
            if (version == "") {
                document.getElementById("versionError").innerHTML = "**Please enter version";
                return false;
            }

        return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input`s should not have end `</input>` tags.

Comment: Did you try to console log inside function `validation()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the `validation()` function when `fieldLabel` is empty then you will **return false**,so the `version` have no chance to execute,change your code as below:

```
   function validation() {
        var fieldLabel = document.getElementById("fieldLabel").value;
        var version = document.getElementById("version").value;
        var isValid = true;
            if (fieldLabel == "") {
            document.getElementById("fieldLabelError").innerHTML = "**Please enter Field label";
            isValid = false;//use a variable to set the result
        }
        if (version == "") {
                document.getElementById("versionError").innerHTML = "**Please enter version";
               isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```